# What would be the best approach to integrate a legacy Drupal backend with Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, drupal, ionic-framework

I am trying to separate the UI layer for a legacy CMS app from Drupal. The immediate solution that comes to mind is to build a RESTful service layer on top of the Drupal architecture for the front end to consume. However, this is going to be a time consuming effort. So, I'm wondering if there's a smarter way to do it? I know we can define the JSON formats and write controllers to deliver it to the front end, but if we would like to avoid coding so much, what options would I have?

Are there any plugins I could use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a smarter way by using a set of drupal contrib modules.
While using these modules you will have ample options for Response formatters like json,xml,jsonp etc

Download drupal modules:

**libraries**

**services**

**services_views**

This link is helpful for you figuring out the intial steps for integrating these modules with your website.

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/services/